# Maintain Liferay session depending upon session in another website

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

#### Two components

1. Liferay site
2. Another web-site on which we do not have any control

#### What we have

We would be using [apache-httpcomponents](/questions/tagged/apache-httpcomponents) to login to the website programmatically through Liferay and get the html page after login. Do some HTML parsing and display the page in liferay.

#### What we need to do (and this is were i need help or pointers)

So what we need to do is this :

1. User logs in to Liferay giving credentials
2. He will only be logged-in when the login is successful in the other website programatically.
3. Once login successful in that application, a session would be created in liferay.
4. Once the user is idle for a certain period and is logged-out of website it should log the user out from Liferay as well.

User base is the same in both the website and liferay but password in liferay are different and not same as those in the website.

#### Also is my approach correct when I am using Apache HttpComponents or is there any other way to do this?

Any help in this direction would help.

Thanks

**<sub>Note: Cross-posted on Liferay Forums - [Maintain Liferay session depending upon session in another website](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/53900509)</sub>**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which is your problem. Liferay log out users automatically when they stop interacting for a time.

Comment: Is this an answer?? Anyways thanks for replying, i am not sure which part is unclear to you but the simple requirement is how to have the session in tandem with the other website, like the other website's session-timeout is 60 but liferay's session time-out is 30 or vice-versa. And how would I login into liferay only when the other website's login is successful? Any pointers? Or is it doable et all?

Comment: Liferay session timeout is set on web.xml file. On ROOT/WEB-INF.

Comment: For the login requiement, as you say, you parse the other website, you have to be sure user has logged in in order to log in Liferay.